# The $w^{*}$-convergent sequences and the Mackey topology on $X^{*}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Recall that the Mackey topology $\mu(X^{*},X)$ on $X^{*}$ is the topology of uniform convergence on weakly compact subsets of $X$. Let $(x^{*}_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $X^{*}$. We say that a sequence $(z^{*}_{n})_{n}$ in $X^{*}$ is a convex block sequence of $(x^{*}_{n})_{n}$ if there is $0=k_{0}<k_{1}<k_{2}<\cdots<k_{n}<\cdots$ so that $z^{*}_{n}\in conv(x^{*}_{i})_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_{n}}$ for all $n$. I am thinking about the following relationship between the $w^{*}$-convergence and $\mu(X^{*},X)$-convergence.

Question. Let $X$ be a Banach space. The following statements are equivalent:

(1) Every $w^{*}$-convergent sequence in $X^{*}$ admits a convex block sequence that is $\mu(X^{*},X)$-convergent.

(2) Every $w^{*}$-convergent sequence in $X^{*}$ admits a convex block sequence that is $\mu(X^{*},X)$-Cauchy.

Thanks!

Comment: Just night thoughts but the unit ball of a dual Banach space is compact for the weak $\ast$ topology, hence complete, even for the Mackey topology.  So being Cauchy or convergent there is the same thing?

Comment: @user131781  Do you mean the Mackey topology on the unit ball $B_{X^{*}}$ is complete?

Comment: yes, yes indeedy